# Magento 2: What is the Downloads Report in report menu?

Tags: magento2

[image]

Any idea about what is the use of this report?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This report is for downloadable products in magento. Magento also gives you the option to create product that user can download.

This report gives you the report of how many times a product is purchased and how many time it is downloaded from My Account page.

If you want to know what is downloadable product, then here is the info for that:

A downloadable product is a type of product that allow shoppers to get it as a file, such as an eBook, music, video, software application, or update. You can put an album on sale and sell each song individually. In addition, you can use a downloadable product to deliver an electronic version of your product catalog. It is very easy to create the downloadable product for your Magento 2 store.
Reference: https://www.mageplaza.com/kb/how-to-create-dowloadable-product-in-magento-2.html

Comment: Thanks for answer.